# add chromium in Lazarus

Tags: chromium, lazarus, freepascal, chromium-embedded

want to add chromium web browser in Lazarus, I was doing the following steps, but couldn't run it in Lazarus. it is saying CEF version is not supported. Can you please kindly advise?

- I am using Lazarus 1.6 in Win7 64bit
- I just downloaded chromium framework from here: https://github.com/dliw/fpCEF3 . As I can see in comments, it is based on CEF 3.2743
- Installed cef3.lpk into Lazarus successfully and Chromium tab added
- downloaded cef_binary_3.2743.1449.g90ba67d_windows64_minimal.tar.bz2 from http://opensource.spotify.com/cefbuilds/index.html and copied the files from Release folder inside my Lazarus executable file and also copied the Resource folder there.
- Also, I tried the last step with cef_binary_3.2743.1449.g90ba67d_windows32_client.tar.bz2 file without any success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, [GitHub/fpCEF3](https://github.com/dliw/fpCEF3) says:

> update to CEF 3.3029

Keep in mind that this number may change in the future (hopely). And lower it says:

> Make sure to use the correct CEF3 version (see the changelog / release tag); other versions (older or newer) may work, but are not recommended

However you are trying version 3.2743, instead of 3.3029 (or whatever it is at the time you are reading this).

Try downloading another version similar to that in GitHub.